# How to check if there are changes made in directory

Tags: windows, cmd

I want to make a script that makes automatic a backup when there are changes made. 
How can I check if there are changes made in de directory, subdirectory and in the files in the directories?

This is my backup script

```
Makebackup

Function Makebackup
    robocopy C:\backup1 /e C:\backup2
End
```

Comment: RoboCopy can wait for changes itself via /MON | /MOT - See the docs

Answer (score 0):

Robocopy can do a DIFF log file. Analyzing log file with your script can help you.

```
robocopy %1 %2 /E /L /FP /log:%3.log
```